# ESP32 smart wifi configuration via esp32 wifi AP(Access Point)

Tags: node.js, react-native

I want to make a React-Native application to provide wifi-credentials to esp32 module via esp32 wifi access point.
I see there are some library of npm that we use to provisioning wifi config to esp32.
For ex.

1. react-native-esp32-idf
2. react-native-esp-idf-ble-provisioning-rn

But i'm confuse how to use them and may be these are provide credentials via BLE or Bluetooth but I want to provide SSID and PASS via wifi.

Means, I have a esp32 module and at begining i use it as a wifi-access-point then my application would be connected to esp32 by wifi automatiically then by communition through wifi-hotspot b/w app and device i provide cred. to device-esp32.

Thats it!

**So how i make this application in react-native?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be like the following:

1. ESP32 is powered up
2. ESP32 opens a Wi-Fi access point
3. ESP32 starts an HTTP server acting as [REST API](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/http_server/restful_server)
4. Any HTTP/REST client (including the react native app) can set the
   Wi-Fi password and SSID using via the REST API
5. Once the Wi-Fi password and SSID are set, ESP32 restarts as a Wi-Fi
   station and tries to connect to the configured Wi-Fi password and
   SSID.

This way on your react native app you'll only need to use a simple [HTTP/REST client](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network)